# jQuery keyup event needs pause between keystrokes

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have an ajax method that fires on the keyup event, but I don't really want it to fire instantly, every single time the user presses a key - ideally I'd like to give a 1-2 second delay before going off to the server, so if the user presses a key every 1/2 second, there will only be 1 call to the server when they finish typing (after 1-2 seconds of not typing anything).

How can I achieve this using jQuery?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var timer = null;
$("#element").keyup(function(){
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function(){
        //do your stuff
    }, 2000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var to;
$("elm").bind("keyup",function(){
  clearTimeout(to);
  to = setTimeout(function(){$.post()}, 3000);
});
```

Comment: You never set `to` to the actual timeout.

Comment: @rlemon You are never assigning the setTimeout to your 'to' variable.  The end result is that your clearTimeout does nothing, and therefore you are still firing the event once for every keyup, just on a 3 second delay.

Comment: @Matt, thanks I corrected that now. Didn't notice, clearly was meant to be set there.